# Windows7 folder sharing in a LAN enviroment

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, home-networking

In my local wireless network, all the computers run Windows 7 Pro.
My network address is 192.168.2.1
All the computers get dynamic ip (e.g 192.168.1.3,4,5 ..) from the router (can be connected via LAN of wifi)

My question: When you do in "Run" or in Folder explorer:
"//192.168.1.10/C$" or "//192.168.1.4" It will take you to that computer file structure (after prompting for user/password ofcourse).

How is this feature called ? and does Windows 7 Home premium include it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Sharing folders via Windows is called SMB or CIFS. However I doubt if you have a home network with one machine on 192.168.2.1 and another on 192.168.1.1 that it would work as they would probably be on different subnets depending on your network config.

Comment: One machine is used a file server and all computers that connect to my network sometimes need files from that machine so they use //blah-server/ and download files.. my question was how this feature called and if its available in Windows 7 Home premium version :) +1 for answer the first part :+)

Comment: I am not 100% certain, but I am pretty confident that you could use a Windows 7 Home Premium client in that scenario. Probably best to wait and see if anyone with Home Premium has tried it. (I avoid the basic versions of windows like the plague)